# Is there any external tool which will give a matching checksum to gzip -lv?

Tags: gzip, md5, checksum, crc, crc32

gzip will give a checksum of each file when given -l and -v options, like so:

```
$ echo foo > foo
$ gzip foo
$ gzip -lv foo.gz
method  crc     date  time           compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
defla 7e3265a8 Dec 10 17:37                  28                   4 150.0% foo
```

Is there any external tool with which I can derive the same checksum?

`md5sum`, `cksum` and `sum` fill a similar role, but do not give the matching code ( hex of 3915528286 is e962385e).

```
$ echo foo > foo
$ md5sum foo
d3b07384d113edec49eaa6238ad5ff00  foo
$ cksum foo
3915528286 4 foo
$ sum foo
00106     1
```

---

Extra detail on the application:

---

We have a filesystem with many large files, and new files are copied in continually. Some of the incoming files match files already existing, in which case we'd like to simply hard-link the pre-existing file, to save disk space. For unzipped files, md5sum's help us make this comparison quickly and efficiently. On the other hand, gzip'd files often have different md5sum for identical data (due to timestamp or owner, which is irrelevant in this application). I notice that gzip will provide a checksum for the internal data, so for two gzip'd files I can simply compare the lists of checksums plus sizes.

I'd also like to support comparing a gzip file to a 'normal' file, in which case I need a utility which will generate the same checksum externally from gzip. I guess the simple solution is to always gzip the plain file before comparing, but this is overhead that I'd like to avoid, since our system is currently bottlenecked by CPU time.

Answer (score 3):

Long story short, I went through the source of gzip, compared it to the source of cksum, made some modifications and then found out that jacksum uses the same implementation as gzip.

So use jacksum. :)

invocation:  jacksum -a crc32 filename

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!
Let me do some bechmarks before I accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

I just ran some benchmarks, and while jacksum is pretty good, it takes slightly longer and uses much more memory than cksfv.

This benchmark was performed in a VirtualBox Ubuntu VM on on a four-gig file generated by `cat /dev/urandom`. You will probably get much better speeds on a "real" machine, but they should be in the same ratio.

The gzip/tempfile method ran out of disk space, but I don't care because it had already used more than twice as much time.

```
$ cksum random.dat
1591530146 4388388864 random.dat
5.78user 7.42system 2:53.62elapsed 7%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2896maxresident)k
8480936inputs+0outputs (0major+225minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ md5sum random.dat
3d6f60f84b2289992abd66428e8a73c4  random.dat
5.57user 8.25system 2:25.97elapsed 9%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2656maxresident)k
8480960inputs+0outputs (1major+209minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ jacksum -x -a crc32 random.dat
c93b4e20        4388388864      random.dat
3.65user 10.82system 2:19.69elapsed 10%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 52224maxresident)k
8490688inputs+152outputs (60major+3936minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ cksfv random.dat
; Generated by cksfv v1.3.14 on 2010-12-11 at 12:06.31
; Project web site: http://www.iki.fi/shd/foss/cksfv/
;
;     93421568  11:16.12 2010-12-11 random.dat
random.dat C93B4E20
4.42user 8.65system 2:14.42elapsed 9%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2048maxresident)k
8480944inputs+0outputs (1major+171minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ bash -c gzip -c random.dat > temp.gz && gzip -lv temp.gz

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
Command exited with non-zero status 1
55.54user 6.68system 4:31.56elapsed 22%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4992maxresident)k
2596536inputs+2689840outputs (3major+695minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I think [cksfv](http://zakalwe.fi/~shd/foss/cksfv/) is my answer.